# Integration of Google Play Services with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I have been trying out **Google Play Services** Multiplayer **APK**, and have tried out the sample code, "Button Clicker" as shown below.

However, I am not sure how to port this over to **LibGDX** as currently the code is running based off a normal project without the "core" and "androidlauncher" that **libGDX** has. Does anyone perhaps have any advise on how should i do it? From what i know, core has a Mainclass with a method called `render()` which always run in a loop. However I cant think of a way of integrating it.

I have checked out several [websites](https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/) , However, could i ask why cant i just place the whole Buttonclicker project into the core module and call methods from it? Like sign in and sign out.

I only require the functionalities currently implemented in Button Clicker

CODE AS FOLLOWS:

```
/* Copyright (C) 2013 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.ryanhello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.OnInvitationReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Participant;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessage;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RealTimeMessageReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.Room;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomConfig;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomStatusUpdateListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.realtime.RoomUpdateListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Button Clicker 2000. A minimalistic game showing the multiplayer features of
 * the Google Play game services API. The objective of this game is clicking a
 * button. Whoever clicks the button the most times within a 20 second interval
 * wins. It's that simple. This game can be played with 2, 3 or 4 players. The
 * code is organized in sections in order to make understanding as clear as
 * possible. We start with the integration section where we show how the game
 * is integrated with the Google Play game services API, then move on to
 * game-specific UI and logic.
 *
 * INSTRUCTIONS: To run this sample, please set up
 * a project in the Developer Console. Then, place your app ID on
 * res/values/ids.xml. Also, change the package name to the package name you
 * used to create the client ID in Developer Console. Make sure you sign the
 * APK with the certificate whose fingerprint you entered in Developer     Console
 * when creating your Client Id.
 *
 * @author Bruno Oliveira (btco), 2013-04-26
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
View.OnClickListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener,
RoomStatusUpdateListener, RoomUpdateListener, OnInvitationReceivedListener {

/*
 * API INTEGRATION SECTION. This section contains the code that integrates
 * the game with the Google Play game services API.
 */

final static String TAG = "ButtonClicker2000";

// Request codes for the UIs that we show with startActivityForResult:
final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;
final static int RC_INVITATION_INBOX = 10001;
final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10002;

  // Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions.
  private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

  // Client used to interact with Google APIs.
  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  // Are we currently resolving a connection failure?
  private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;

  // Has the user clicked the sign-in button?
  private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

  // Set to true to automatically start the sign in flow when the Activity starts.
  // Set to false to require the user to click the button in order to sign in.
  private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;

    // Room ID where the currently active game is taking place; null if we're
    // not playing.
    String mRoomId = null;

// Are we playing in multiplayer mode?
    boolean mMultiplayer = false;

// The participants in the currently active game
    ArrayList<Participant> mParticipants = null;

// My participant ID in the currently active game
    String mMyId = null;

// If non-null, this is the id of the invitation we received via the
// invitation listener
    String mIncomingInvitationId = null;

// Message buffer for sending messages
    byte[] mMsgBuf = new byte[2];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .build();

// set up a click listener for everything we care about
for (int id : CLICKABLES) {
  findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(this);
}
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent;

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_single_player:
        case R.id.button_single_player_2:
            // play a single-player game
            resetGameVars();
            startGame(false);
            break;
        case R.id.button_sign_in:
            // user wants to sign in
            // Check to see the developer who's running this sample code read the instructions :-)
            // NOTE: this check is here only because this is a sample! Don't include this
            // check in your actual production app.
            if (!BaseGameUtils.verifySampleSetup(this, R.string.app_id)) {
              Log.w(TAG, "*** Warning: setup problems detected. Sign in may not work!");
            }

            // start the sign-in flow
            Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in button clicked");
            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        break;
        case R.id.button_sign_out:
            // user wants to sign out
            // sign out.
            Log.d(TAG, "Sign-out button clicked");
            mSignInClicked = false;
            Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
            break;
        case R.id.button_invite_players:
            // show list of invitable players
            intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 3);
            switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
            break;
        case R.id.button_see_invitations:
            // show list of pending invitations
            intent = Games.Invitations.getInvitationInboxIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_INVITATION_INBOX);
            break;
        case R.id.button_accept_popup_invitation:
            // user wants to accept the invitation shown on the invitation popup
            // (the one we got through the OnInvitationReceivedListener).
            acceptInviteToRoom(mIncomingInvitationId);
            mIncomingInvitationId = null;
            break;
        case R.id.button_quick_game:
            // user wants to play against a random opponent right now
            startQuickGame();
            break;
        case R.id.button_click_me:
            // (gameplay) user clicked the "click me" button
            scoreOnePoint();
            break;
    }
}

void startQuickGame() {
    // quick-start a game with 1 randomly selected opponent
    final int MIN_OPPONENTS = 1, MAX_OPPONENTS = 1;
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(MIN_OPPONENTS,
            MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    resetGameVars();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SELECT_PLAYERS:
            // we got the result from the "select players" UI -- ready to create the room
            handleSelectPlayersResult(responseCode, intent);
            break;
        case RC_INVITATION_INBOX:
            // we got the result from the "select invitation" UI (invitation inbox). We're
            // ready to accept the selected invitation:
            handleInvitationInboxResult(responseCode, intent);
            break;
        case RC_WAITING_ROOM:
            // we got the result from the "waiting room" UI.
            if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // ready to start playing
                Log.d(TAG, "Starting game (waiting room returned OK).");
                startGame(true);
            } else if (responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
                // player indicated that they want to leave the room
                leaveRoom();
            } else if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Dialog was cancelled (user pressed back key, for instance). In our game,
                // this means leaving the room too. In more elaborate games, this could mean
                // something else (like minimizing the waiting room UI).
                leaveRoom();
            }
            break;
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
                + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
              BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,requestCode,responseCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}

// Handle the result of the "Select players UI" we launched when the user clicked the
// "Invite friends" button. We react by creating a room with those players.
private void handleSelectPlayersResult(int response, Intent data) {
    if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.w(TAG, "*** select players UI cancelled, " + response);
        switchToMainScreen();
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Select players UI succeeded.");

    // get the invitee list
    final ArrayList<String> invitees = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);
    Log.d(TAG, "Invitee count: " + invitees.size());

    // get the automatch criteria
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
    int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
    int maxAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
    if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0 || maxAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
        autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "Automatch criteria: " + autoMatchCriteria);
    }

    // create the room
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating room...");
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
        rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    }
    switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    resetGameVars();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Room created, waiting for it to be ready...");
}

// Handle the result of the invitation inbox UI, where the player can pick an invitation
// to accept. We react by accepting the selected invitation, if any.
private void handleInvitationInboxResult(int response, Intent data) {
    if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.w(TAG, "*** invitation inbox UI cancelled, " + response);
        switchToMainScreen();
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Invitation inbox UI succeeded.");
    Invitation inv = data.getExtras().getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);

    // accept invitation
    acceptInviteToRoom(inv.getInvitationId());
}

// Accept the given invitation.
void acceptInviteToRoom(String invId) {
    // accept the invitation
    Log.d(TAG, "Accepting invitation: " + invId);
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    roomConfigBuilder.setInvitationIdToAccept(invId)
            .setMessageReceivedListener(this)
            .setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    resetGameVars();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.join(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfigBuilder.build());
}

// Activity is going to the background. We have to leave the current room.
@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "**** got onStop");

    // if we're in a room, leave it.
    leaveRoom();

    // stop trying to keep the screen on
    stopKeepingScreenOn();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
      switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
    }
    else {
      switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    }
    super.onStop();
  }

// Activity just got to the foreground. We switch to the wait screen because we will now
// go through the sign-in flow (remember that, yes, every time the Activity comes back to the
// foreground we go through the sign-in flow -- but if the user is already authenticated,
// this flow simply succeeds and is imperceptible).
@Override
public void onStart() {
    switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      Log.w(TAG,
          "GameHelper: client was already connected on onStart()");
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG,"Connecting client.");
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    super.onStart();
}

// Handle back key to make sure we cleanly leave a game if we are in the middle of one
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && mCurScreen == R.id.screen_game) {
        leaveRoom();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}

// Leave the room.
void leaveRoom() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Leaving room.");
    mSecondsLeft = 0;
    stopKeepingScreenOn();
    if (mRoomId != null) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, this, mRoomId);
        mRoomId = null;
        switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
    } else {
        switchToMainScreen();
    }
}

// Show the waiting room UI to track the progress of other players as they enter the
// room and get connected.
void showWaitingRoom(Room room) {
    // minimum number of players required for our game
    // For simplicity, we require everyone to join the game before we start it
    // (this is signaled by Integer.MAX_VALUE).
    final int MIN_PLAYERS = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Intent i = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, MIN_PLAYERS);

    // show waiting room UI
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}

// Called when we get an invitation to play a game. We react by showing that to the user.
@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
    // We got an invitation to play a game! So, store it in
    // mIncomingInvitationId
    // and show the popup on the screen.
    mIncomingInvitationId = invitation.getInvitationId();
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.incoming_invitation_text)).setText(
            invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName() + " " +
                    getString(R.string.is_inviting_you));
    switchToScreen(mCurScreen); // This will show the invitation popup
}

@Override
public void onInvitationRemoved(String invitationId) {

    if (mIncomingInvitationId.equals(invitationId)&&mIncomingInvitationId!=null) {
        mIncomingInvitationId = null;
        switchToScreen(mCurScreen); // This will hide the invitation popup
    }

}

/*
 * CALLBACKS SECTION. This section shows how we implement the several games
 * API callbacks.
 */

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onConnected() called. Sign in successful!");

  Log.d(TAG, "Sign-in succeeded.");

  // register listener so we are notified if we receive an invitation to play
  // while we are in the game
  Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);

  if (connectionHint != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: connection hint provided. Checking for invite.");
    Invitation inv = connectionHint
        .getParcelable(Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION);
    if (inv != null && inv.getInvitationId() != null) {
      // retrieve and cache the invitation ID
      Log.d(TAG,"onConnected: connection hint has a room invite!");
      acceptInviteToRoom(inv.getInvitationId());
      return;
    }
  }
  switchToMainScreen();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() called. Trying to reconnect.");
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() called, result: " + connectionResult);

  if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() ignoring connection failure; already resolving.");
    return;
  }

  if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
    mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
    mSignInClicked = false;
    mResolvingConnectionFailure = BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient,
        connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));
  }

  switchToScreen(R.id.screen_sign_in);
}

// Called when we are connected to the room. We're not ready to play yet! (maybe not everybody
// is connected yet).
@Override
public void onConnectedToRoom(Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectedToRoom.");

    //get participants and my ID:
    mParticipants = room.getParticipants();
    mMyId = room.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleApiClient));

     // save room ID if its not initialized in onRoomCreated() so we can leave cleanly before the game starts.
     if(mRoomId==null)
      mRoomId = room.getRoomId();

    // print out the list of participants (for debug purposes)
    Log.d(TAG, "Room ID: " + mRoomId);
    Log.d(TAG, "My ID " + mMyId);
    Log.d(TAG, "<< CONNECTED TO ROOM>>");
}

// Called when we've successfully left the room (this happens a result of voluntarily leaving
// via a call to leaveRoom(). If we get disconnected, we get onDisconnectedFromRoom()).
@Override
public void onLeftRoom(int statusCode, String roomId) {
    // we have left the room; return to main screen.
    Log.d(TAG, "onLeftRoom, code " + statusCode);
    switchToMainScreen();
}

// Called when we get disconnected from the room. We return to the main screen.
@Override
public void onDisconnectedFromRoom(Room room) {
    mRoomId = null;
    showGameError();
}

// Show error message about game being cancelled and return to main screen.
void showGameError() {
    BaseGameUtils.makeSimpleDialog(this, getString(R.string.game_problem));
    switchToMainScreen();
}

// Called when room has been created
@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRoomCreated(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomCreated, status " + statusCode);
        showGameError();
        return;
    }

   // save room ID so we can leave cleanly before the game starts.
    mRoomId = room.getRoomId();

    // show the waiting room UI
    showWaitingRoom(room);
}

// Called when room is fully connected.
@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRoomConnected(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomConnected, status " + statusCode);
        showGameError();
        return;
    }
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onJoinedRoom(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
    if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
        Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomConnected, status " + statusCode);
        showGameError();
        return;
    }

    // show the waiting room UI
    showWaitingRoom(room);
}

// We treat most of the room update callbacks in the same way: we update our list of
// participants and update the display. In a real game we would also have to check if that
// change requires some action like removing the corresponding player avatar from the screen,
// etc.
@Override
public void onPeerDeclined(Room room, List<String> arg1) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onPeerInvitedToRoom(Room room, List<String> arg1) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onP2PDisconnected(String participant) {
}

@Override
public void onP2PConnected(String participant) {
}

@Override
public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> arg1) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> peersWhoLeft) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onRoomAutoMatching(Room room) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onRoomConnecting(Room room) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onPeersConnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

@Override
public void onPeersDisconnected(Room room, List<String> peers) {
    updateRoom(room);
}

void updateRoom(Room room) {
    if (room != null) {
        mParticipants = room.getParticipants();
    }
    if (mParticipants != null) {
        updatePeerScoresDisplay();
    }
}
```

`My current interface code` 
    package com.macrohard.game;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.macrohard.game.SomeGame;

import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;

import com.macrohard.game.ActionResolver;
import com.macrohard.game.MainMenu;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver {
private GameHelper gameHelper;
private final static int requestCode = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(false);

    GameHelper.GameHelperListener gameHelperListener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed(){ }

        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded(){ }
    };

    gameHelper.setup(gameHelperListener);
    //initialize(new SomeGame(), config);
    initialize(new MainMenu(this), config);
}

//...

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void signIn()
{
    try
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log in failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

@Override
public void signOut()
{
    try
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                gameHelper.signOut();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log out failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

@Override
public void rateGame()
{
    String str = "Your PlayStore Link";
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
}

@Override
public void unlockAchievement()
{

}

@Override
public void submitScore(int highScore)
{

}

@Override
public void showAchievement()
{

}

@Override
public void showScore()
{

}

@Override
public boolean isSignedIn()
{
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX separates platform specific codes into different modules for providing multiplatform by using the same code base (Core project). So you should implement android specific stuff in android project as you show in the code example.

You can not use any class in the package "com.google.android" in your core project. Because Google Play Services depends on android specific resources. You should read the document about platform specific code

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

So, you should prepare an interface which defines your methods you want to use and implement separately for each of platforms that you are planning to support in your project.

Comment: Hello! thanks for your advise! I have read the documentation and implemented a interface that defines my methods. Currently i am only able to the signing in of google play to be working, but after that nothing else happens as i do not know where to place the next few methods, E.g i want to create a multiplayer room using Roomconfig similar to the button code posted above. Do you have any advise on where to place it? May i also ask why is the sign in automatically initiated? i only intialised the action resolver to the mainactivity but didnt call any methods such as signIn()

Comment: Do you happen to have a example of a LibGDX implementing multiplayer services? And is there anyway i could keep in contact with you? Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we are both trying to implement a real-time multiplayer using the *Google Play Games Services* with the very specific architecture of any *libGDX* project. I suggest you to check out this *GitHub* repository : [GarrapuchoFootball](https://github.com/rianos/GarrapuchoFootball). Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: Alright I will have a look at it! thank you! is there anyway i could get in contact with you too?